# Mongodb find field with dot in collection with 1M documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to find the query to find all the fields/keys in the collection with 1M records. The field is a nested field (field under a field under field). But I end up getting this error with output any suggestions on how to overcome this ??

```
mr = db.runCommand({
  "mapreduce" : "MyCollectionName",
  "map" : function() {
    var f = function() {
      for (var key in this) {
        if (this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          emit(key, null)
          if (typeof this[key] == 'object') {
            f.call(this[key])
          }
        }
      }
    }
    f.call(this);
  },
  "reduce" : function(key, stuff) { return null; },
  "out": "MyCollectionName" + "_keys"
});
print(db[mr.result].distinct("_id"));
```

lmdb> print(db[mr.result].distinct("_id"));

getting this error:
**MongoServerError: distinct too big, 16mb cap**

I am fairly new to mongodb, so forgive my ignorance…

Answer (score 0):

Once you create new collection containing all the field names. You seem to be using distinct on "_id" field for this collection, "_id" are unique by definition, so can just run `"db.{collectionName}.find({})"` instead of distinct. Also, [mongo docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/distinct/#mongodb-dbcommand-dbcmd.distinct) explicitly state that distict results must not exceed max BSON size (16 Mb).

> Results must not be larger than the maximum BSON size. If your results exceed the maximum BSON size, use the aggregation pipeline to retrieve distinct values using the $group operator, as described in Retrieve Distinct Values with the Aggregation Pipeline.

You can use use aggregate option for that. Like this:

```
db.{collectionName}.aggregate( [ { $group : { _id : "${fieldName}" } } ] )
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to fetch all the fields in this case, so will db.{collectionName}.aggregate( [ { $group : { _id : "${fieldName}" } } ] ) . work for this as well ?? coz i see that it is asking to ${fieldName} inside agregate ??

Comment: No, I meant to use aggregation only for the second part. You should use aggregation instead of distinct. For getting all field names mapReduce is perfectly fine. I've updated my answer to incorporate this fact.